# visual studio code search word without wrap around

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every editor including notepad has a "wrap around" option for search, and I can't believe it that for vscode I coudn't find a way to turn off wrap around when searching.
Is there a way to do it?
I find it really inconvinient searching with "wrap around" on, because it's hard to tell whether I have reached the end when using keyborad short cut to go next quickly.
Also, I use vscodevim, and it doesn't have wrapscan option, either.

Comment: I think that F4 and Shift-F4 don't wrap.

Comment: @harrymc, F4 no effect, you mean F3 and shift-F3? It does wrap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158475/disable-search-wrap-in-vs-code

Answer (score 1):

There is corresponding feature request in VSCode GitHub repo that was simply closed without being implemented. Here it is - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46504 .

Related question on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158475/disable-search-wrap-in-vs-code .